# how to delete a file with the `less` pager

Tags: linux, terminal, less

### Usage

I'm viewing a file with `less` and I want to delete it. (I go over my day's scratch notes in `less` because it's fast and can easily handle dozens of notes, and sometimes I want to delete a note.)

### Question

How do I do that, and is there a keybinding I can set in `~/.lesskey` or `~/.lessrc`?

Comment: and you want to do it from 'less' rather than with the 'rm' command, because it'd be faster?  (I presume you know the rm command?)?   I'd be stunned if you could delete a file with less.  I was surprised to discover that less has a lessrc file.  It's really just a small command designed just for what it does.  Like many things in *nix, or like many things are meant to be in *nix.. one little tool for a task, and if need be, chain tools together with pipes.  The tool to delete a file is rm.

Comment: I'm aware of the Unix philosophy. In keeping with that, `less` allows you to run shell commands with `!`. I'm really just looking for a way to get the filename so I can feed it to `rm` and bind that functionality to a hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can put the following in `~/.lesskey`:

`#command
^D shell rm "%"\n`

Turns out the syntax for referring to the current file is the same as Vim's.

Comment: interesting.. btw there is a unix.stackexchange.com  you may have been able to get an answer there.